# Filling a 2D polygone with N points more or less equally distanced

Tags: waypoints

Following challenge: having any number of connected 2D faces forming virtually a polygone and filling the polygone with a variable number of points equally distanced to each other.

So here is a sample 2D object with any number of faces, all connected to each other, forming virtually a polygone:

[image]

Here is what I would like to calculate (in JavaScript or Python or pseudo): a variable number of points inside the faces, equally distanced to each other.

[image]

Some notes:

The points distance to each other doesn't need to be 100% the equal.
Prioritized points are at the borders of the faces
I should be able to define the targeted number of points, but it doesn't need to be exactly that number of points, can be more or less.
Any ideas how to approach?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [Lloyd's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm).  You'd confine the search space to the area contained within the original polygon, but would perform the iterations normally otherwise.

Comment: For seeding the initial point placements inside the polygon, you might want to look at generating a Poisson disc distribution. [Mike Bostock has some great descriptions and visualizations of algorithms for generating them on this page](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/). From there you should only need a couple of iterations of Lloyd's algorithm to converge on a good distribution (mostly to help snap points onto the boundaries, which OP wants to prioritize).This is easier to parametrize by spacing rather than a target number of points, though.